# Why are request cookie poperties null or incorrect on ASP.NET postback?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm debugging the HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookie values in an ASP.NET web application, and finding the only property correctly populated is the Value. The Domain and Path are null, and the Expires value is set to DateTime.Min.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those values are not available in the Request.Cookies collecton.  They are only used when you are "setting" the value.  You can verify this with a network trace.  In the request headers, the client browser only sends the name/value pairs in the "Cookie" header.

Comment: Hi David, would you know where I can find official documentation about this behaviour?