# What is the best way to get support from microsoft developers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a problem at my production web, that I am not able to solve.
 I am not able to reproduce the problem in stage or development. It only appears when the website is under heavy load.

I think it is solvable if somebody who has a very good understanding of the internals of FormsAuthentication would have a look at it by logging into our system. It should be at least Scottgu!

Somebody told me that Microsoft Premier Support is a good choice for this kind of problems. We have no MSDN subscription or other connection to microsoft that enables us to use MPS.

Is there a way to get support on a incident base? Are there other ways to get this kind of support?

**EDIT**
Here is the problem itself:
[Different users get the same cookie - value in .ASPXANONYMOUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448720/different-users-get-the-same-cookie-value-in-aspxanonymous)

Comment: "It should be at least Scottgu" LOL

Comment: Premier support, IIRC, *is* incident based. You, of course, have to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb266240.aspx) has the phone numbers for support incidents.  I imagine you might be able to give them a credit card number if you are not an MDSN subscriber.  Surely they would be able to route you appropriately to help you spend money with their support team.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Advanced Support](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/advancedef)

$259-$515/incident.

Answer (score 1):

Try reproducing it first.  I've had good experience with WAPT for load testing.
If you do call MS support be prepared to spend a long time on this.  It is possible to get to people who are very knowledgeable but they are about 3-4 layers down (or up?) from where you start the call.
If it is authentication issue authdiag (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e90fe777-4a21-4066-bd22-b931f7572e9a&DisplayLang=en) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the stack trace? I would start by trying to solve it on your own.  Try using a web stress tool such as the free WCAT IIS tool from Microsoft to try and replicate the traffic.

Comment: I updated the post. I put some load on the server using Jmeter, but I could not simulate the traffic in a way that the error would occur. Its not the traffic itself, but the traffic has to have some kind of pattern. 
Is WCAT able to replay real traffic?