# How do you get AnonymousID from cookie ASPXANONYMOUS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, anonymousidentification

If I have a look at my cookievalue .ASPXANONYMOUS it is a string ie

WZnX-rXHygEkAAAAOTFhZjE5YTctZmEzZi00MTMwLWEwNTAtYjYwMzI0N2M0NTY4gQUsRlThiJWAjBgmBnpeIba7eGo1

The value Request.AnonymousID is a Guid.

How do you get from ASPXANONYMOUS  to AnonymousID ?

I need this to debug some issues I have with FormsAuthentication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, an anonymous id is a GUID. The cookie string is an encrypted value containing the id and other data:

```
[Serializable]
internal class AnonymousIdData
{
    internal string AnonymousId;
    internal DateTime ExpireDate;

    internal AnonymousIdData(string id, DateTime dt);
}
```

By default, anonymous cookies are valid for 90 days and are refreshed every visit.

You can treat Request.AnonymousID as the request username when Request.IsAuthenticated==false.

see [AnonymousIdentificationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.anonymousidentificationmodule.aspx)

UPDATE:
In response to a comment, yes, you can decode the value, but why?

```
string aId = Request.AnonymousID;

string anonCookieValue = Request.Cookies[".ASPXANONYMOUS"].Value;
MethodInfo method = typeof(AnonymousIdentificationModule).GetMethod("GetDecodedValue", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object anonymousIdData = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { anonCookieValue });
var field = anonymousIdData.GetType().GetField("AnonymousId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
string anonymousId = (string) field.GetValue(anonymousIdData);
field = anonymousIdData.GetType().GetField("ExpireDate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
DateTime expired = (DateTime) field.GetValue(anonymousIdData);

// why? just use Request.AnonymousID    
Debug.Assert(aId == anonymousId);
```

Comment: Can you decrypt the cookie string?

Comment: Valid question. I guess because I want to totally mess up my application :-)

But the real nswer is this problem I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448720/different-users-get-the-same-cookie-value-in-aspxanonymous

Comment: **WHY?** Because sometimes you have access to cookies, but no (reasonably good or appropriate) access to Request.AnonymousID. For example in signalr and webapi.

Comment: Several years later, I needed to do this because of code executing in the OnAuthenticateRequest event, whereas the AnonymousID is only supplied to HttpRequest during OnPostAuthenticateRequest