# Simple password protection on a page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, machinekey

I wish to secure individual (dynamic) pages in an ASP.NET MVC application.

I do not want to use a full blown authentication system - we are already using forms authentication for the administrators of the site. Instead, this is so that we can send out links to a page with a password for specific users.

The way I am handling this currently is when a valid password is submitted we create an encrypted cookie containing the page id (Guid) and their session id and redirect them to the page. In our "Page" controller action we then validate this cookie.

So first question, is this the best (most secure) approach (aside from using forms authentication)?

Second question, can I read the machine key used by Forms Authentication to perform the encryption, or better yet use the FormsAuthentication to encrypt the cookie (the only overload I can see is one that requires a FormsAuthenticationTicket)?

Since we always generate a new machine key before deploying it would be better if all our encryption used the same key.

[Update]

Regarding how to access the machine key I found my answer at http://rich-rogers.com/archive/asp.net-c-sharp-encrypt-hash-using-machinekey-values

[Update 2]

I realize after asking this question that since I will need to maintain a list of pages that they do have access to, I would probably be better off just storing these in the current session. I can store a list of security tokens with an expiry date. Since I already have a wrapper around session, this should be easy to unit test too.

Answer (score 1):

To make really secure your cookie-key, you need to make it available only on SSL pages, or else some one can get it, and even if its encrypted he can use it.

```
    Request.Cookies[cookieName].HttpOnly = true;
    Request.Cookies[cookieName].Secure = true;
```

Also to read: [Can some hacker steal the cookie from a user and login with that name on a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498599/can-some-hacker-steal-the-cookie-from-a-user-and-login-with-that-name-on-a-web-si)