# What prevents someone sniffing a network to steal and use asp.net authentication cookies?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've tried searching and found questions that were close to this, but I could not find one answer that actually details this exact issue.

What (if anything) prevents a user from sniffing a network, getting all the asp.net forms authentication cookies a site is sending to me (or sniff the cookies I'm sendint to the server), setting those cookies in their own browser and viewing the site as the authenticated user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can some hacker steal the cookie from a user and login with that name on a web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498599/can-some-hacker-steal-the-cookie-from-a-user-and-login-with-that-name-on-a-web-s)

Answer (score 0):

Inherently, I don't think there's any native mechanism to prevent the scenario you describe. I think that's one reason MS recommends that Forms Authentication cookies have a very limited lifespan (set a short Expiration time), and be communicated across SSL.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is the only thing that can prevent it.