# Something wrong with cookies in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, formsauthentication, formsauthenticationticket

I am building a web application and when a user signs in, his credentials are first validated against the database. If the credentials are correct, a FormsAuthenticationTicket is created. Then a cookie is created from that ticket. The Expires and Path properties are set. See below.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket=new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.User.UserName, 
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), RememberMeCheckBox.Checked,
model.User.Id.ToString()+" "+model.User.UserType.ToString());
string cookieStr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieStr);
cookie.Expires=ticket.Expiration; 
cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.Redirect("DummyForm.aspx");
```

And when I redirect the response to a new page, in the Page_Load event the presence of a cookie is checked.

```
HttpCookie cookie=HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath];
if(cookie!=null)
{
    //Do stuff
}
else
{
  //Do other stuff
}
```

When I run the application, it behaves like the cookie variable is null.
Is there something that I have omitted?
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
cookie.Domain="localhost";
cookie.Name="My auth cookie";
```

I also set the domain property to localhost in web.config. However, it still doesn't work. I used the developer tools of Google to check the cookie and I can't see it there.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506532/session-would-not-retain-values-and-always-return-null/12506833#12506833  and the settings - you must have set the correct domain name to work

Comment: I did not set a domain name. Can I set just any name, since the web application is still under development?

Comment: Still not solved. ???

Comment: the cookie name, must be with out spaces.