# Login doesn't work for ASP.NET website within IFRAME using IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iframe

The login mechanism for our ASP.NET website works fine except when it is loaded inside an iframe in Internet Explorer v11. As a normal website, it works fine on IE.  The login ids and passwords are stored in SQL Server and a select query is run every time the user clicks on login. Further, I am using Forms Authentication within web.config. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Are there any actual details you can share? Why are you using an iframe in the first place?

Comment: @SeanLange I don't get an error message. The login page just refreshes and the id/password fields are cleared out. We are using iframes so that our clients can use our web application as part of their website.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506532/session-would-not-retain-values-and-always-return-null/12506833#12506833

Comment: Have you tried debugging on a local server to what is happening? You will have to attach to process since you are using a iframe.

Comment: so I add my website's URL to the trusted sites in IE and it works. Does anyone know if I can make any changes in my code so as to over come this? @SeanLange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We published our P3P policy on the website and this resolved the error.