# Strange behavior with ASP.NET session cookie, CSRF tokens and Ajax Calls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cookies

we are experiencing an odd situation when validating CSRF tokens. Here is the sequence of events with the tokens replaced by letters:

1. User logs out. Gets redirected to home page.

   `Session.Abandon();
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`
2. A new session is created with a new session id (S1) and a new CSRF token (T1).

   `protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
       Token = NewToken();
   }`
3. The home page loads and fires a JS Ajax request which carries token (T1) for validation. From inspection, we know that for some reason this request carries a **blank** ASP.NET_SessionId cookie (`ASP.NET_SessionId=;`) when it should have session id (S1). Hence, it is treated as a new session on the backend and step 2 is repeated for this request. Backend now has new session id (S2) and new token (T2).
4. The backend continues servicing the Ajax request. It compares token (T1) to token (T2) and it fails.
5. Subsequent calls on the site after either refreshing the page or navigating to another page succeed without issue. Ajax requests carry the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie and everything works as expected. They execute under session id (S1) and Token (T1).

We have managed to partially track down the issue to the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie being set to `HTTP Only`:

```
Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
```

If we remove this, it works on both, the first request after log out as well as subsequent requests. The `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie is sent on all Ajax calls.

We [obviously] want to keep the cookies secure, so removing `Secure = true` is not an option.

Why do Ajax requests on the first page load after logout **not** pass a value for the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie but subsequent requests do? It's almost like the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie is not ready or available in JS for the initial request after load, but can be read in subsequent requests (navigation/reload).

Comment: check that you make an `https` call when you read and set the cookie - also  check the 'domain' as on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506532/session-would-not-retain-values-and-always-return-null/12506833#12506833

Comment: @Aristos: I'll take a look at the settings you mentioned. The entire site is running exclusively on `https`. Thanks!