# Hide ASP.NET_SessionId Cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-cookies, sessionid, sql-session-state

I wrote an ASP.Net MVC app that stores Session information in the database, but I can see the session id being stored in a browser cookie "ASP.NET_SessionId".  Is this a security risk?  Can the id be used to hack/steal a user's session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can some hacker steal the cookie from a user and login with that name on a web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498599/can-some-hacker-steal-the-cookie-from-a-user-and-login-with-that-name-on-a-web-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session id in the cookie is used to relate a stateless web request to stored state on the server.

With regard to security I don't think the ASP.NET_SessionId contains authentication details - that's the .ASPXAUTH (if you are using the built in .NET membership providers). I think it can, in some circumstances be used to steal a users session.

A great read on this is Troy Hunt's blog, particularly this post [Anatomy of an insufficient transport layer protection attack](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-9.html) where he packet sniffs the cookies of wifi users in a McDonalds and logs in as them.

Comment: That blog post is comprehensive. Thanks.